# Ratio and Percentage

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What ratio should be used to prepare a mixture of 100% (absolute) alcohol with 20% chlorhexidine solution and water to end up with a mixture of 70% alcohol and 2% chlorhexidine (considering the 80% of water in that chlorehexidinde)?

Answer (score 1):

Mixture A has 1L of alcohol, 0L of water, 0L of chlorhexidine, per liter.

Mixture B has 0L of alcohol, .8L of water, .2L of chlorhexidine, per liter.

Mixture C (the goal), has .7L of alcohol, .28L of water, .02L of chlorhexidine, per liter.

You want to find $x,y$ such that $x$L of mixture A, plus $y$L of mixture B, yields $(x+y)$L of mixture C.

Comment: Hello vadim123, thanks for your fast response, but I little bit confused, what is 0.18L of water, and how to solve (x+y)L of mixture C?

Comment: Sorry, 0.18L should be 0.28L.  The reason is that the end product does not just contain alcohol and chlorhexidine, it also contains water.

Comment: Do you mean 1L alcohol - 0.7L= 300 mL; 0.2L chlorhexidine - 0.02L= 180 mL; 1000 mL - (300 + 180 mL) = 520 mL water?

Comment: Hi vadim123, I think I was worng, 0.7L alcohol = 700 mL, 0.02 mL chlorhexidine= 20 mL, 0.28L water = 280 mL, isn't it!

Comment: that's right, you've got it.

Comment: Hello vadin123 again, but 20 mL of 20% chlorhexidine contains 4 gm chlorhexidine, and if you add 280 mL water whould give up about 1.4% conc. of chlorhexidine, isn't it right?